# Dereferencing struct void pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

I have a MyLib.h which has

```
typedef void *MyThread;
```

and a MyLib.c which has:

```
typedef struct
{
ucontext_t *context;
int tid;
}_MyThread;
```

there is a test function that creates a thread and issues a join as:

```
void f0(void * dummy)
{
  MyThread t1;
  printf("f0 start\n");
  t1 = MyThreadCreate(f1, NULL);
  _MyThread *t = (_MyThread*)t1;
  printf("passed value=%d\n",t->tid);

  printf("f0 join on t1\n");
  MyThreadJoin(t1);
....
}
```

MyThreadCreate and MyThreadJoin in MyLib.c are as follows:

```
MyThread MyThreadCreate(void(*start_funct)(void *), void *args)
{
   _MyThread child_thread; 
   ... 
   //setting the child thread's tid 
   child_thread.tid = ++active_threads;
   ... MyThread ret = (MyThread)&child_thread;
   return ret;
}

int MyThreadJoin(MyThread thread)
{
    _MyThread *arg_thread;
    arg_thread = (_MyThread*)thread;
    int id = arg_thread->tid;
....
}
```

My problem is, when I run the above, I get:

```
passed value=2
f0 join on t1
arg_thread->tid = 13
```

The passed value = "2" is correct, however the value "13" that comes up inside the library function is wrong. Why is the passed value dereferenced in the same way coming different from calling function and different in called function?

Comment: You pass a pointer to a pointer (a `void**`), but the function accepts a pointer (a `void*`). (edit: actually, maybe not. Still trying to understand your code…)

Comment: Right OK, you're casting a `void*` to a `void**`, instead of taking a pointer to it. You should do `t = &t1` and `arg_thread = &thread;`. With your current code, you're switching around pointer types all over the place and making a mess of the memory.

Comment: The passed value, that is function f0 is correct. However, it prints wrongly in the MyThreadJoin function.

Comment: Are you passing the same structure to different threads?  If so, you run into synchronization problems.

Comment: as I said, your casts are wrong. This code can be written without using any casts at all. Try doing that, and your problem will go away. In the future, I strongly recommend *not* hiding pointers behind typedefs, and using forward declarations instead of using `void` pointers.

Comment: Can you show what `MyThreadCreate()` does?

Comment: MyThread MyThreadCreate(void(*start_funct)(void *), void *args)
    {
        _MyThread child_thread;
        ...
        //setting the child thread's tid
        child_thread.tid = ++active_threads;
        ...
        MyThread ret = (MyThread)&child_thread;
        return ret;
    }

Comment: Please note the difference between MyThread (which is a typedef void*, thats the way the requirement is) and typedef struct _MyThread which is the structure defined within the library.

Comment: inline `MyThread MyThreadCreate(void(*start_funct)(void *), void *args)
{
 _MyThread child_thread; 
... 
//setting the child thread's tid child_thread.tid = ++active_threads;
 ... 
MyThread ret = (MyThread)&child_thread; return ret; 
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you add code to print out the memory address of arg_thread and t. I have a feeling what is going on is that your pointer is being sliced in half by a cast. Is MyThreadJoin being forward declared in  MyLib.h correctly? Are you compiling your code as 64 bit?

[edit]
I just saw your comment where you were creating t. It looks like you are allocating it on the stack,(not the heap). When you go up a stack frame, it's memory hasn't been overwritten. When you push a new function on to the stack, it overwrites the memory on t. The simple solution is to malloc the struct in your construction function.

Comment: I tried printing the addresses of both, and the address are coming as same for both, t in f0 and arg_thread in the MyThreadJoin function. Yes, I am compiling on a 64 bit machine.

Comment: Thanks. What you are saying makes a lot of sense now. I infact tested that over multiple calls to MyThreadCreate and then MyThreadJoin, the value that I get remains the same.
Could you please explain in maybe a short code how I should correct this problem?